# How to add a data to the plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How can I have the line plot, with the data coming one by one?
I have the code

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
plt.plot(1, 2)
plt.pause(2.5)
plt.plot(2, 5)
plt.pause(2.5)
```

but it does not show the line, if I add 'o' option in `plot` function or change the `plot` function to `scatter` function, it works fine, But I want a line with no markers, how can I do this?

Comment: Your example creates, with your two `plot` calls, two "lines" with a single point each, so if you don't have any markers, it's invisible to the eye. Add your data to lists for x and y instead and plot those.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @DominikStańczak If so, should I delete the current plot and plot a new one each time I want to update the plot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animating "growing" line plot in Python/Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074461/animating-growing-line-plot-in-python-matplotlib)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To respond to the comment about "deleting the current plot", and to improve upon Stefano's answer a bit, we can use Matplotlib's object-oriented interface to do this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(min(x), max(x)), ylim=(min(y), max(y)))

plt.ion()

(line,) = ax.plot([], [])  # initially an empty line

timestep = 0.5  # in seconds

for i in range(1, len(x) + 1):
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
    plt.pause(timestep)
plt.show(block=True)
```

This version uses a single [`Line2D` object](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html) and modifies its underlying data via `set_data`. Since Matplotlib doesn't have to draw multiple objects, just the one line, it should scale better once your data becomes large.

Comment: Thanks! Instead of using `ax.set()` at start, I won't have the data at start, it comes one by one, so can it change the limit of x and y axis dynamically, instead of call `ax.set()` each time a data comes? (if I use scatter() it just expend the limit automatically if needed, can this be like that?)

Comment: It's not THAT smart :D but you can keep track of the min-max info for both axes yourself, pretty efficiently too (without looping, as you're just comparing old min/max and new value) and call ax.set again within the data loop only if the min/max changes.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following code, according with my tests it works only if the plot is generated in an external window:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True)

x = [4, 1, 5, 3, 8]
y = [1, 2, 9, 0, 2]

ax.set_xlim(0, 9)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 10)

for j in range(1, len(x)):
     X = [x[j-1], x[j]]
     Y = [y[j-1], y[j]]
     ax = plt.plot(X, Y, mew = 5, ms = 5)
     # mew and ms used to change crosses size
     plt.pause(1)# one second of delay
     plt.show()
```

If you are working on Spyder, in order to make the intepreter generating an external window whenever you call a plot you have to type

```
%matplotlib qt
```

on the intepreter (and not into the script file!) BEFORE running the previous lines of code